# Recycler view add image from gallery or camera with button

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am working on an app where I have to upload images to a `recycler view` from either the gallery or from camera. The recycler view should have a button where I can add the image from.

The image below shows what I am trying to achieve.

My question is, is there a library for `android` either `java` or `kotlin` that can help me achieve this?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: This is what I am trying to achieve]

Comment: Glide and Piccaso are the most famous ones to show images

Comment: @javdromero I am aware of those, but is there a library to implement the recyclerview as such , with the plus at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [UltimateRecyclerView](https://github.com/cymcsg/UltimateRecyclerView) library for your purpose

This library supports different layouts and many more other useful features. You can create different layouts for images and plus button and define different code logic by checking the position of the clicked item.